# How to print an int as a binary in C?

Tags: c

I have a C code where I want to print all numbers until certain range in binary. I have the following code, but the printing part doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE UINT_MAX

const char *byte_to_binary(unsigned long int x)
{
    static char b[33];
    b[0] = '\0';

    unsigned long int z;
    for (z = SIZE; z > 0; z >>= 1)
    {
        strcat(b, ((x & z) == z) ? "1" : "0");
    }

    return b;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", byte_to_binary(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want it to be flexible, so when I change the SIZE constant, I want it to work properly for any value until the biggest integer value which seems to be `unsigned long int`.

Comment: This program is wrong, `SIZE` should be `sizeof(unsigned long int) * CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: Perhaps because `UINT_MAX` is not the single bit you imagine it to be.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work correctly": Are you not *sure* it is incorrect?  If you are sure, it would help to explain how the results differ from what you expect.

Comment: this function is very buggy. after you call it a second time, the return value of the first time will be changed unexpectedly. try to malloc then free.

Comment: `#define SIZE UINT_MAX  unsigned long int i; for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
    {` -> potential infinite loop should `UINT_MAX == ULONG_MAX`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SIZE` should have a single bit that is `1` as MSB.
You can change your program to achieve this following way:

```
#define SIZE (UINT_MAX ^ (UINT_MAX >> 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

In the program it's necessary to know the number of bits of `unsigned long int` type, since you are interested in fill a char array with characters representing those bits.

An unsigned integer type in C needs N+P bits, where N is the amount of bits used in the binary representation of the number, and P are the padding bits.
The presence of padding bits is very uncommon for the home-PC user, but they cannot be forgotten.

On the other hand, in C we cannot say for sure that 1 byte == 8 bits.
We only can assure that 1 byte is at least 8 bits.

So, a precomputation like `8*sizeof(unsigned long)` for SIZE would be wrong.

To obtain the most significant bit representable in `unsigned long` we need to use the ULONG_MAX constant joint to some trick.

```
 #define MOST_SIGNIF_UL (ULONG_MAX ^ (ULONG_MAX >> 1))
```

**Edited paragraph:** While I was typing this answer, the user **Eugene Sh** posted first the earlier formula. Anyway, in this post I explain other details to improve the code of the OP.

The constant MOST_SIGNIF_UL now holds the binary value consisting of a 1 followed by N - 1 zeroes, being N the number of binary digits for `unsigned long`.

This constant is at disposal in compile-time and it works independently of the number of bits in a byte, the presence or absence of padding bits, and the number of bytes of `unsigned long int` in the underlying system.
If `unsigned long` has 32 value bits, then the constant above is equal to 2³¹, thus giving a binary object with the most significant bit put to 1 and the rest 0.

You are using `static char[]` for your array.
I think this is not a well method for "exporting" a char array to the caller.
It's prefirable to create an object of type `char*` (by allocating memory for it) and to return that pointer. You can "destroy" this object when you want, just by deallocating its memory.

```
#include <limits.h>  /* Use ULONG_MAX */
#include <stdio.h>

#define MOST_SIGNIF_UL (ULONG_MAX ^ (ULONG_MAX >> 1))

char * byte_to_binary(unsigned long int x)
{
    /* Precomputation of number of bits for unsigned long value bits: */
    /* This piece of code would have to be outside to be computed only once. */
    int bitcount = 0;
    for(unsigned long z = MOST_SIGNIF_UL; z > 0; z >>= 1)
        bitcount++;

    char *b = malloc(bitcount + 1);

    for (unsigned long int k = 0, z = MOST_SIGNIF_UL; z > 0; k++, z >>= 1)
    {
       b[k] = (x & z)? '1' : '0';
    }

    b[bitcount] = '\0';  /* End of string */

    return b;
}

int main(void)
{
  char *str = byte_to_binary(131073); /* Create object str */
  printf("%s", str);
  free(str);                          /* Destroy object str */
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the conditional operator only needs to evaluate `(x & z)` instead your more elaborated version `(x & z) == z`.
The reason is that `z` has only the k-th bit "on" (that is, "1") and any other bit is "off" (that is "0"). So, the k-th bit of `x` is 1 if and only if `(x & z) != 0`.

Also, the header `<string.h>` is avoided, because the function `strcat()` has been omited (using `strcat()` in this context is not efficient).

The precomputation of `bitcount` could be done outside of the function for best efficiency, but I left this detail for you.

Answer (score 1):

This will adapt to whatever type you declare in the `#define`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define mytype unsigned long int

const char *byte_to_binary(mytype x)
{
    static char b[8*sizeof(mytype)+1];
    mytype z = 1 << (8*sizeof(mytype)-1);
    b[0] = 0;
    while (z) {
        strcat(b, (x & z) ? "1" : "0");
        z >>= 1;
    }
    return b;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", byte_to_binary(12345678));
    return 0;
}
```

I leave the loop in `main()` to you - I can't believe you really want to print such a large range.

Comment: Minor thoughts: `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(mytype)` is more portable than `8*sizeof(mytype)`.  Also, consider what prints with `printf("%s %s\n", byte_to_binary(123), byte_to_binary(456));`

Comment: Use `(mytype) 1` rather than `1` in `1 << (8*sizeof(mytype)-1)`

Comment: @chux your second comment about (cast) is good, but the first would apply to any library function that returns a pointer to a locally declared static variable. However you missed the fault where my answer says *whatever type* but the right shift of supposedly 1 bit set fails for `signed` types, and the loop never ends. Additionally, I thought `CHAR_BIT` applied to  the `char` type and not to the byte size of memory or registers.

Comment: `sizeof()` returns the size in `char` units.   `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a `char`.  This is _at least_ 8.  It is commonly 8, but current esoteric and old systems have values like 9, 16,32,36.  So `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(mytype)` is the bit size of a type.

Comment: Agree if `mytype` is some signed integer, the while loop is problematic.  To be clear: the comment about casting `(mytype) 1` was to insure `1` was sufficiently wide enough for the shift of `(8*sizeof(mytype)-1)`.  But given padding bit, etc. @Eugene Sh. approach is more portable.

Answer (score 0):

`UINT_MAX` will evaluate to the largest value that a unsigned integer can represent, which will be 0xFFFFFFFF (and so on until all bits are used), instead of 0x80000000, which is what I assume you want.

You can figure out how many bits are in the variable (i.e. `8*sizeof(unsigned long int)`), so you can create the initial mask from that, e.g.

```
int size = 8 * sizeof(unsigned long int);
for (z = 1 << (size - 1); z > 0; z >>= 1)
{
    strcat(b, ((x & z) == z) ? "1" : "0");
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't take care about padding bits.

Comment: @pablo1977 - what do you mean by padding bits in this context?

Comment: You say: *You can figure out how many bits are in the variable (i.e. 8*sizeof(unsigned long int))*: There are two wrong assumptions there: **(1)** The number of bits of a byte are assumed to be 8; **(2)** there are not any padding bits.

Answer (score 0):

It is that you are making multiple calls without resetting array so you will get 32 chars for 0 then again 32 for 1 and again for 2 and so on. `CHAR_BIT` will hit you for portability reasons if byte is not 8 bits. Assuming 32-bit longs. `memset` your entire array to 0.

Comment: `strcat` should take care of null termination

Comment: `b[0] = '\0';` is correct. it makes the string initially to be empty

Comment: @EugeneSh. Agreed that `strcat` will take care of that. But `b[0] = '0'` looks plain wrong.

Comment: @user902384 Why? `b[0] = '\0'` just makes the `b` to be empty string.

Comment: Ah missed that part. :-) Silly me. Edited answer.

Answer (score -5):

Something like this may work:

```
template <typename Number>
std::string as_binary(Number n) {
   std::string ret;
   for (size_t i  = (sizeof(n)*8)-1; i >= 0; --i)) {
     ret += ( (n & (1 << i)) ? "1" : "0"  )
  }
  return ret;
}
```

**Update:**

Ok, the previous was a C++ implementation written in notepad, of course it had errors, but the user should be able to correct them. I think that's the point, I prefer "You can do it this way" vesrus the whole "This is the way" thing.

Anyway, a solution writen in C, should **might be** like the following (implemented using int, can be easily updated to any other integral type)

```
ichramm@hypernova:~$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char * as_binary(unsigned int n, char *buffer, int size) {
    int i = (sizeof(n)*8);
    assert(i < size);
    memset(buffer, 0, size);
    for (i = i-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        strcat(buffer, (n & (1u << i)) ? "1" : "0" );
    }
    return buffer;
}

int main() {
    char buff[33];
    printf("%d %s\n", 1, as_binary(1, buff, 33));
    printf("%d %s\n", 2, as_binary(2, buff, 33));
    printf("%d %s\n", 4, as_binary(4, buff, 33));
    printf("%d %s\n", 8, as_binary(8, buff, 33));
    printf("%d %s\n", 16, as_binary(16, buff, 33));
    printf("%d %s\n", 31, as_binary(31, buff, 33));
    printf("%d %s\n", 32, as_binary(32, buff, 33));
    return 0;
}

ichramm@hypernova:~$ gcc -g test.c -o test
ichramm@hypernova:~$ ./test 
1 00000000000000000000000000000001
2 00000000000000000000000000000010
4 00000000000000000000000000000100
8 00000000000000000000000000001000
16 00000000000000000000000000010000
31 00000000000000000000000000011111
32 00000000000000000000000000100000
```

Comment: ok, it's c++, the += part can be changed by strcat, and the template can be removed

Comment: @slugonamission yes, because the most significant bit goes first

Comment: I was stating that you had `++i` instead of `--i`, but you've fixed it now.

Comment: If posting an answer that doesn't work is your idea of "You can do it this way", I'll be sure to steer clear of your future answers.

Comment: @ScottHunter You're right, I had to re-read stack overflow rules in order to understand this simple thing, incomplete answers should be posted as comments instead. Thanks!